# Redis connection closes when multiple tests are running in the same time

Tags: redis, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have few test cases in one class and only one will succeed but all others are failed with redis pool exception. How can I make sure other tests can also get the connection from pool?

```
[error]    JedisConnectionException: : Could not get a resource from the pool  (Pool.java:22)
[error] redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:22)
[error] org.sedis.Pool.withJedisClient(sedis.scala:79)
[error] com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin$$anon$1.set_(RedisPlugin.scala:147)
[error] com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin$$anon$1.set(RedisPlugin.scala:106)
[error] play.api.cache.Cache$.set(Cache.scala:58)
[error] controllers.Security$ResultWithToken.withTokenShort(Security.scala:51)
[error] controllers.Security$ResultWithToken.withTempToken(Security.scala:62)
[error] controllers.Security$$anonfun$HasToken$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Security.scala:83)
[error] controllers.Security$$anonfun$HasToken$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Security.scala:83)
[error] controllers.Security$$anonfun$HasToken$1.apply(Security.scala:82)
[error] controllers.Security$$anonfun$HasToken$1.apply(Security.scala:76)
[error] play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221)
[error] play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
    at org.apache.commons.pool.BaseObjectPool.assertOpen(BaseObjectPool.java:137)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1065)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:20)
```

This is my controller class which sets a uuid token to the play cache which sets to redis by play-redis-plugin. The play cache calls RedisPlugin and then get a pool from jedis client. This controller class will be used in all apis which want to return a auth token.

```
trait Security { self: Controller =>

  implicit val app: play.api.Application = play.api.Play.current

  lazy val CacheExpirationShort =
    this.app.configuration.getInt("cache.expiration").getOrElse(8 * 60 * 60) // 8 hrs

  val AuthTokenCookieKey = "XSRF-TOKEN"

  /* additional methods to handle token passing */
  implicit class ResultWithToken(result: SimpleResult)(implicit req: RequestHeader) {
    def withTokenShort(token: (String, String)): SimpleResult = {
      Cache.set(token._1, token._2, CacheExpiration)
      MemberToken.add(token._2, token._1)
      val isSecure = req.headers.get("X-Scheme").collect {
        case "https" => true } getOrElse { false }
      result.withCookies(Cookie(AuthTokenCookieKey, token._1, Some(CacheExpirationShort), path="/", domain=Some(App.cookieDomainFromHost(req.host)), secure=isSecure , httpOnly=false))
    }
  }
object Security extends Controller with Security
```

EDIT1:

According to this SO [Play ! 2.2.4 / Akka : tests failed when run together, but ok separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888041/play-2-2-4-akka-tests-failed-when-run-together-but-ok-seperately), I think at RedisPlugin, jedisPool should change to a def.

```
 lazy val jedisPool = {
   val poolConfig = createPoolConfig(app)
   Logger.info(s"Redis Plugin enabled. Connecting to Redis on ${host}:${port} to ${database} with timeout ${timeout}.")
   Logger.info("Redis Plugin pool configuration: " + new ReflectionToStringBuilder(poolConfig).toString())
   new JedisPool(poolConfig, host, port, timeout, password, database)
 }
```

Comment: Can you post where and how you're using them?

Comment: @LimbSoup I updated my post for where I used redis-plugin and jedis.

Comment: @angelokh I think this is due to some heavy memory usage. Can you try increasing the memory allocation of your jvm?

When compiling / testing please try "-Xms512m" or more like 1024 / 2048. at the run parameter

Comment: @RGAT No, I tried export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms800m -Xmx1500m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m", then run 'play test'. It doesn't work.

Comment: @angelokh I assume that you are using multi threading?

http://www.alexecollins.com/content/5-tips-unit-testing-threaded-code/

Comment: @RGAT I'm using Play 2.2 and Play's plugin for redis which I assume multi-threaded.

Comment: Are you using this play plugin? https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis. Will try to replicate the error. We have a project that is using play framework as well. We might encounter this issue.

Comment: @RGAT yes, I'm using this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems the best solution (as long as you are not testing Redis itself) is to just disable the Redis plugin for tests and let it use the default cache.

```
val config = Map(
  "ehcacheplugin" -> "enabled",
  "redisplugin" -> "disabled")

"this test" should {
  "not die" in {
    running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = config)) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```